# Multiple options for the same `case` result in `bash`

Tags: bash, case

I’m not sure this is even possible to achieve in `bash`, but my script is of the form

```
case "$1" in
  --one)
    echo "one"
    ;;
  --two)
    echo "two"
    ;;
esac
```

And I’d like to give a smaller form to `--one` (something like `-o`). Is there some available construct, like `--one) || --o)` or `(--one|-o))`, that will give this result, or do I have no other option other than just specifying them separately and give them the same commands?

Comment: Well, yes it is, thank you. I was having trouble finding that since I wasn’t sure of what keywords to search for, and none of the examples used it. Please add your comment as an answer, and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`)` symbol is just a delimiter for a specific case pattern, so `--one ) || -o )` isn't right. Instead just provide a list of patterns separated by `|` symbol:

```
case "$1" in
  --one | -o )
    echo "one"
    ;;
```